# Cannot load controller, Codeigniter request returns a 404 error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot load all controller after index.php.  Codeigniter request responds:

> 404 page not found

My codeigniter version is 3.0.

**Controller demo:**

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Reg extends CI_Controller {

    public   function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('reg_model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('toa_form_validation');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('register/reg.php');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    public function aut()
    {
        $meli_code=filter_var($this->input->post('meli_code'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $re_password=$this->input->post('re_password');
        $tellphone=filter_var($this->input->post('tellphone'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $capt=$this->input->post('capt');
        $ruls=array(
            array(
                'field'   => 'meli_code',
                'label'   => 'roll',
                'rules'   => 'code_meli|required|melicode_check[' . $meli_code . ']'
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 'password',
                'label'   => 'roll ',
                'rules'   => 'required|matches[re_password]|max_length[10]|password_ch[' . $password . ']'
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 'tellphone',
                'label'   => 'roll',
                'rules'   => 'required|tellphone['.$tellphone.']'
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 're_password',
                'label'   => 'roll',
                'rules'   => 'required'
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 'capt',
                'label'   => 'roll ',
                'rules'   => 'callback_capt_check|required'
            )
        );
        //  $this->form_validation->set_rules("password","roll",'required|matches_array[input---conf_password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('required','%s');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('matches','roll');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($ruls);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('register/reg.php');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->reg_model->insert_first_info($meli_code,$password,$tellphone);
            $this->session->set_userdata(array('activepanel'=>1,'code_meli'=>$meli_code,'tellphone'=>$tellphone,));
            redirect(site_url('bank/'), 'refresh');
        }
    }

    function capt_check($str)
    {
        //echo $str;
        if ($str != $this->session->userdata('capt'))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('capt_check', 'roll');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }

    function loginuser()
    {
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('register/login.php');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

    function loginauh()
    {
        $meli_code=filter_var($this->input->post('meli_code'), FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $capt=$this->input->post('capt');

        $ruls=array(
            array(
                'field'   => 'meli_code',
                'label'   => 'roll ',
                'rules'   => 'code_meli|required'
            ),
            array(
                'field'   => 'password',
                'label'   => 'roll ',
                'rules'   => 'required|max_length[10]|password_ch[' . $password . ']|login['.$meli_code.']'
            ),

            array(
                'field'   => 'capt',
                'label'   => 'roll',
                'rules'   => 'callback_capt_check|required'
            )
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_message('required','%s');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules($ruls);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == false)
        {
            //echo $this->reg_model->user_login($meli_code,$password);

            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('register/login.php');
            $this->load->view('footer');

        }
        else
        {
            $active_user=$this->reg_model->get_active_user($meli_code);

            $this->session->set_userdata(array('activepanel'=>1,'code_meli'=>$meli_code,'active_user'=>$active_user));

            redirect(site_url('bank'), 'refresh');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe the URL you are using follows the correct routing pattern that CI uses. I suggest you double check how it's supposed to work, and ensure you are doing it correctly. My guess is the request should go to `/controller/`, not `/index.php/controller`.

Comment: thanks problem is sloved files name  in controller most is upercase!!